# Выбор метрики качества для оптимизации в задаче несбалансированной бинарной классификации (10%)

Tags: машинное-обучение, классификация, метрики, xgboost

Чем руководствоваться при первоначальном выборе метрики в задаче бинарной классификации в несбалансированном наборе данных  (10% цели)?

Веса:

- false negative = -20
- false positive = -5
- true positive = 20

Что лучше выбрать?

> auc,  aucpr, ndcg@, map@

Можно ли перебрать несколько метрик для определения лучшей?

Comment: советую почитать: https://machinelearningmastery.com/tour-of-evaluation-metrics-for-imbalanced-classification/ и посмотреть на [метрики из imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-imblearn.metrics)

Comment: А как вы собираетесь определять"лучшую" метрику?  Просто интересно. Ту, что даст самое высокое значение?

Comment: @passant по результатам на новых данных. Выбрать самое высокое значение не получится, т.к. они измеряют не одно и тоже.

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо за ссылки, удалось продвинутся. К aucpr добавила f2

Comment: @Анна Лебедева - так и я о том. Ну построили вы модель. Ну посчитали свои метрики на "новых данных". Что дальше-то. Как выбрать лучшую. Вы правильно заметили, что "они измеряют не одно и то-же". Это я вас плавно подвожу к решению, что ответ на "Можно ли перебрать несколько метрик для определения лучшей?" - отрицательный.